# nginx keepalive and dns resolver

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a nginx instance in AWS that has upstream Application layer.

There are two requirements for nginx
- keepalive
- use resolver to dynamically resolve the upstream

I am able to make either of them work.

Here is the config for making keepalive work:

```
upstream "backend" {
    server "appserver.example.com:443";
    keepalive 250;
}

server {           
    resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=60s;
    server_name _;
    location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass https://backend;
    }
}
```

Here is the config for DNS resolver to work:

```
 server {           
    resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=60s;
    server_name _;
    set $backend appserver.example.com:443;
    location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass https://$backend;
    }
}
```

How can I get both DNS resolver and keepalive to work without using a third-party plugin in open source NGinx

Comment: This can be natively done with using Nginx Plus. I wonder why upstream keep alive is required, is the given upstream server located elsewhere from Nginx and the latency in between high?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Nginx wiki page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/domain_resolve/#example)
there seems to be the [jdomain Plugin](https://github.com/wdaike/ngx_upstream_jdomain)

```
http {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    upstream backend {
        jdomain  www.baidu.com;
        # keepalive 10;
    }
    server {
        listen       8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
}
```